# For Tensorflow Inception v3 examples, Why C++ classifier runs much slower than python one?

Tags: performance, tensorflow

I'm running example / how-to given in Tensorflow documentation that are given at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

For some reason, python classifier (./tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py) runs much faster than C++ classifier (./tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc).  I expected otherwise.  Can anybody tell me why it is the case?

- environment: windows8.1 pro (core i7) + HyperV + Docker environment (without GPU).
- label_image (C++ example) takes 30sec.
- classify_image (python example) takes 3sec.
- I run once before measurement to make sure data is downloaded.
- I see a lot of Warning at label_image runtime.

  > W tensorflow/core/kernels/batch_norm_op.cc:36] Op is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().

Comment: The discussion at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1502 suggests that the fused C++ implementation of batchnorm is slower than the Python non-fused version

Comment: I get those warrning as well any idea about them?